# email me when external ip changes

Tags: networking, bash, email

I'm trying to write a bash script for my server. What this script does is runs curl to get the latest IP address of my box and then email me if it's different from the old IP address stored in a file.

This is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
#if ip address changes do
x=$(curl -4 "icanhazip.com")
y=$(cat ./oldIP.txt )
if [ "$x"!="$y" ];
    then
    echo "Current IP Address is $x"
    echo "Previous IP address is $y"
#   y=$x
elif [ "$x"="$y"]
    then
    echo "The IP addresses are the same"
fi
#send email to me
```

I tried using `if; then; else;` as well however I cannot get the script to react differently when the IP addresses are the same.

I believe the issue stems from my variable declaration for `$y`.

Answer (score 1):

You must leave spaces between operands within test brackets [ ].

```
#!/bin/bash
#if ip address changes do
x=$(curl -4 icanhazip.com )
y=$(cat ./oldIP.txt )
if [ "$x" != "$y" ]
    then
    echo "Current IP Address is $x"
    echo "Previous IP address is $y"
#   y=$x
else
    echo "The IP addresses are the same"
fi
#send email to me
```

Comment: I did find that, and end up fixing the space on the closing bracket of line 5 however the issue persisted, it still ignored my else statement.

Comment: It's odd though, vim highlights the syntax properly. However I tried elseif and added if [ "$x" = "$y" ] and I noticed the second time $y was called it highlighted red instead of purple. (Default ubuntu colors)

Comment: In bash, "else if" is spelled `elif`

Comment: In your code you have another [ ] clause at 10-th row with the same problem. I replaced it with `else` statement. Just copy my code and check it.